# Apache Proxy Plugin handling of JVM ID in JSESSION Cookie

Tags: apache2, weblogic, jsessionid

I am trying to understand the mapping between the JVMID present in the JSESSION Cookie and the ipaddr:port of the managed server. Few questions below -

1. Who generates the JVMID and how does apache plugin know the JVMID of a given node. Does it get it back in the response from the server (may be as part of the Dynamic Server List?).
2. If we send a request to an apache with a JSESSION cookie containing a JVMID, and that apache hasn’t handled any requests yet, what would be the behavior?
3. Assuming that apache maintains a local mapping between JVMIDs and node addresses, how does this get updated? (specially in case of apache restart or a managed server restart)

   - See more at: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=654#comment-9054

Answer (score 1):

1) The JVM ID is generated from each Weblogic server and appended to the JSESSIONID.

Apache logs the individual server HASH and maps it to the respective Managed server, and is able to send it to the same weblogic managed server as the previous request.

Here is an Example log from http://www.bea-weblogic.com/weblogic-server-support-pattern-common-diagnostic-process-for-proxy-plug-in-problems.html

```
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 getpreferredServersFromCookie: -2032354160!-457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 GET Primary JVMID1: -2032354160
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 GET Secondary JVMID2: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 [Found Primary]: 172.18.137.50:38625:65535
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 list[0].jvmid: -2032354160
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 secondary str: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 list[1].jvmid: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 secondary str: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 [Found Secondary]: 172.18.137.54:38625:65535
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 Found 2 servers
```

2) If the plugin is installed on the new Apache as well, the moment Apache starts up it will ping all available Weblogic servers to report them as Live or Dead (*my terms used here, not official*) - while doing that health check it gets the JVMID for each available Weblogic. After that when it will receive the first request with a pre-existing JVMID - it can direct correctly.

3) there are some params like DynamicServerList ON - if it's On it keeps polling for Healthy Weblogics, if OFF then it send it to a hardcoded list only. so if On - then it's pretty dynamic